# How do I login as root on MySQL on OS X?

Tags: mysql, macos, osx-lion, mysql-error-1064

I've just set up MySQL on my computer (OS X 10.7), and it seems to be working, judging by the "mysqld" in the activity monitor and the new icon in my System Preferences.

However I'm having trouble doing anything with MySQL, as I need to login at least as the root user, but it doesn't let me.  So let's run through what I've been doing and what error messages I'm getting:

Firstly, I start up MySQL via the "mysql" unix executable file.  This seems to work, as my entries are now preceded with

```
 mysql>
```

Also, I can type

```
 help;
```

and I get MySQL's help list.  So then I go to do something, like create a database:

```
 CREATE DATABASE books;
```

but I get the following error:

```
 ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'books'
```

So then I figure I need to login, and that logging in as the root user should be enough.  I enter the following:

```
 mysql -u root -p;
```

But I get the 1064 error saying my syntax is wrong.  I've had a look around through a number of websites, and this never seems to be a problematic step.  Any clues on what's going wrong for me?

Comment: `mysql -u root -p root;`

Comment: why don't you create DB through programming lang u are using? I always create using Java...

Comment: Still get the same 1064 error code..

Comment: Can I build a good database through Xcode for OS X?  I still wouldn't mind figuring out how to get mysql to work, as it is a fairly common database solution.

Comment: show me your code... what language are you using?

Comment: How did you install mysql? Mac Ports? Homebrew? Some other way?

Comment: for xcode, I believe it uses mysqli...

Comment: you keep saying `1064` the error code listed in the question is `1044` which is it?

Comment: @FahimParkar I suppose it's Cocoa - the standard language in Xcode.  At the moment I'm learning to build iOS apps, and I'm now needing to have a database structure to hold data in.  Ultimately I need a solution with the best integration with iOS and OS X apps, so perhaps building it directly into my app will be the answer.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson Both.  When I try to some standard commands, like create a database, I get the 1044 restricted user error code.  When I try login as the root user, I get the 1064 syntax error code.

Comment: @andrewb : sadly I am also begineer for iOS. Still reading checklist part... don't have much idea about DB there...

Comment: @FahimParkar I guess I'll sort that out another time.. for now I should be able to get MySQL working somehow, just need to figure out this login issue.  I have a feeling I was meant to create a group or something, as I haven't done any of that.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

At the **OSX Terminal prompt** you enter `mysql -u root` to actually start the command line client that connects to the server.

`shell>` represents whatever your shell prompt actually looks like.

You do **not** enter this in *after* you have already typed `mysql` at the command line prompt.

Here is an example session:

```
shell> mysql -u root
mysql> SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('newpwd');
mysql> SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'127.0.0.1' = PASSWORD('newpwd');
mysql> SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'::1' = PASSWORD('newpwd');
mysql> SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'host_name' = PASSWORD('newpwd');
```

> *NOTE:* you might need to preface the `shell> mysql -u root` with `shell> sudo mysql -u root`

My shell prompt is customized to be`[jhr@Blackintosh] [/usr/local/mysql-5.5.25a-osx10.6-x86_64/bin]` with a `\n` on the end so `./mysql -u root` it typed at the on the next line down. The rest is what the output of that command should be. The shell prompt is replaced by the prompt of the `mysql` program prompt.

#### Here is what my shell output looks like

```
[jhr@Blackintosh] [/usr/local/mysql-5.5.25a-osx10.6-x86_64/bin] 
./mysql -u root
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 5
Server version: 5.5.25a MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2011, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
```

Comment: So you mean run that code without first running the mysql exec file?  When I did, I got -bash: mysql: command not found

Comment: Sorry for the late response, had work.  Anyway I think we're getting closer to my issue.  So my "shell>" is "Andrews-MacBook-Air:~ Andrew$ " - just the raw terminal.   When I type in "mysql -u root" it says "-bash: mysql: command not found".  Do I need to set up some sort of MySQL group?  I installed the most recent DMG file by clicking on the three packages, as instructed.  Was there anything else to do?

Comment: @andrewb no offense but at this point you need some rudimentary Unix skills to get past your problems if what is posting in my answer isn't obvious what you need to do. Look at the `path` in my example at the bottom of my answer. Start reading the instructions and how to's, all the information you need is on the MySQL website.

Comment: Fair call, no offense taken. I don't really know anything about unix commands, so guess I need to look into that. I'll try report back here when I figure out where I was going wrong.

Comment: Alright I sorted it out.  So "mysql" for you actually referred to the directory to the "mysql" unix exe file.  I typed in the full directory then followed it by the u root bit, so: "/usr/local/mysql-5.5.25a-osx10.6-x86_64/bin/mysql -u root;".  And that worked.  Thanks for the help, now to learn MySQL!

Answer (score 9):

Executing this command:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

Will prompt on your console:

```
#:=> Enter password: [enter your pass]
```

That way you can login mysql dbms

Answer (score 0):

`mysql -u root` if you have a password setup, or `mysql -u root -p root` if you don't.

This will prompt the `root` password.
I always use the mac terminal anyways. When you install, just using `mysql` you can log in, and you can setup the password for the `root`.
I also advice you to read [Creating a MySQL user](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-user.html)

Comment: I still get the syntax error (error 1064).  I'm meant to be entering this via MySQL right, not through the terminal without MySQL running?  I've tried with and without MySQL and it doesn't work - always get syntax error.  Also I haven't set up any groups or users so far.

Comment: that is because what ever you are entering isn't the correct syntax! what they are telling you to do is start the `mysql` client at the prompt with this syntax, you aren't doing that, you are entering that syntax *after* you enter `mysql` client, and that as you have been told over and over is a syntax error.

Comment: @andrewb I always use the mac terminal. First, set the password for the `root` from the link I've shared. Then try logging with `mysql -u root -p`. I would advice you to create a database. In your example, the "owner" of the database is root (you may not be able to access it)

Comment: But I've been entering it in as instructed!
mysql> mysql -u root -p root;

Comment: @andrewb you have to create the database from the mac terminal. I never ever created a user / database from the programming language I'm using.

Comment: @andrewb `ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'books'` does not have a user. Try creating an user first, then create the database and start using it.

Comment: @andrewb you still don't get my point. you don't enter `mysql> mysql -u root -p roo` you enter `mysql -u root -p root` at the main OSX terminal prompt to actually start the `mysql` client!

Comment: @philippe I have been working through the mac terminal.  I run the unix executable file, which runs through the terminal.  Also shouldn't I just be able to use the root user instead of making a new user?  I'm guessing there's something wrong with my setup with the root user login not working, though I'm really not sure what it would be.

Answer (score 0):

i was having this problem recently and realized my login path was bin/bash so incase anyone else has this problem heres how i fixed it. if you have XAMPP installed go to your applications folder then go to the XAMPP folder. then go to the bin folder. if you are in the bin folder, this will be your path to use the following command

```
mysql -uroot
```

now open your terminal application and on the top left click on terminal and then preferences. where it says "shell open with", select the default option then close your terminal window. now reopen it and your terminal should start like this

```
 Last login: Mon Dec 18 12:06:25 on ttys
 [yourname]-air:~ [yourname]$
```

now type the path

```
 /Applications/XAMPP/bin/mysql -uroot
```

Answer (score -1):

When you first start using mysql on mac none of the accounts have passwords, not even root. So you can login with root and no password and then you must set passwords as explained by Jarrod, or for more detail read:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/default-privileges.html

Comment: Thanks for the response.  However my issue is that I'm unable to even login as root, so can't really do the rest you suggested.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to try to login as root without password, like:  mysql -u root;  ... have you tried it that way?

Comment: Yes I have, have had no success though